# How to adjust font size based on screen scaling level?

Tags: html, css

is there a way in CSS to make font size change dynamically (adjust) according to screen zoom level?

Lets say on a regular monitor I want to use 16px font.

But when the page opens in HDTV, which is 1080P screen with Display Setting scale = 150% I want the font to become, lets say 12px?

Is this doable? I am using bootstrap, not sure if that's related.

Comment: Using Bootstrap has nothing to do with it. You'd need to edit CSS and to add some media queries in order to achieve this. Take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to make font-size responsive. You can use any of these unit. You can find more details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

- rem - Relative to font-size of the root element
- **vw - Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport***
- **vh - Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport***
- **vmin - Relative to 1% of viewport's* smaller dimension**
- **vmax - Relative to 1% of viewport's* larger dimension**
- % - Relative to the parent element

*I widely use vw and vh for responsive design and you may try with bold points unit*

> Tip: The em and rem units are practical in creating perfectly scalable
>   layout!
>   * Viewport = the browser window size. If the viewport is 50cm wide, 1vw = 0.5cm.